# Openstack to one machine

Tags: juju, maas, cloud

I want to use juju to deploy `openstack`.

I want to install - `mysql`,`rabbitmq`,`quantum`,`glance`,`cinder`,`opnestack-dashboard`,`keystone` and etc. on two nodes /the one is bootstrapped/.

I install the `juju-gui` on the bootstrapped node -`machine"0"` and the elements of openstack on `machine"1"`

I make the relations with the GUI but when I try to enter in the horizon dashboard I get

```
"internal error 500"
```

Is it because I used only one machine ?

What should I do to resolve the problem?

Comment: What version of openstack are you using? And can you type python on a terminal and then type `import django;django.VERSION` and paste the output to your question?

Comment: 1.5.4 final version when i type python

Comment: @Jobin Are you sure this is the same problem?

Comment: Pretty much yes, the scenario mentioned by both of them are the same.